# from jasper report to xls - style issue

Tags: jasper-reports

I try to create xls from my jasper's report (jrxml file) from java.

All work fine but style is not applied.

This is style

```
<style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#ededed"  isBold="true" fontName="Arial Black" >
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#d4d4d4"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#d4d4d4"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#d4d4d4"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#d4d4d4"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#d4d4d4"/>
    </box>
</style>
```

This is a part of table

The style isBold="true" fontName="Arial Black" are ignored.

Furthermore i want change text color but which is property?

Add code of element

```
<jr:column width="140" uuid="980fffb5-1088-47a6-b00f-b5d08b7093c9">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
    <jr:tableHeader height="15" style="Table_TH">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="140" height="15" uuid="16679b95-2e6e-4ca1-b8b6-dd7b74267c56"/>
            <text><![CDATA[CHIAVE]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </jr:tableHeader>
    <jr:detailCell height="15" style="Table_TD">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="140" height="15" uuid="341e7faf-9680-4941-a9a4-ac78b8f4aae0"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{typology_key}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </jr:detailCell>
</jr:column>
```

Comment: You should post the small example to reproduce the issue (how this style is using). Maybe you are override this style with element's attributes

Comment: The added code is for one column

Comment: 1) Are you using font extensions? 2) Did you try to set font and bold directly via *staticText*'s attributes? 3) Are you sure that name of font is correct? 4) You should post xml definition of fonts

Comment: 1)yes 2) I set attribute on report element and work( why?) 3)yes . If you post answer I will mark it as accepted answer